# Delete category method is not working

Tags: magento, collections, magento-1.7, categories, catalog

I want to delete empty categories and sub categories. I tried the below script. But Its not deleting the category from admin panel. My magento version is 1.7.0.2

```
$categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('level', array('gteq' => 2))
;

foreach($categoryCollection as $category) {
    if ($category->getProductCount() === 0) {
        $category->delete();
        //$category->setId($category->getId())->delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly ask for the product counts to be added to your category collection :

```
$categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('level', array('gteq' => 2))
    ->setLoadProductCount(true);
```

Else `$category->getProductCount()` will return `null`, which is not `=== 0`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('level', array('gteq' => 2))
;

foreach($categoryCollection as $category) {
    if (!$category->getProductCount()) {
        $category->delete()->save();
        //$category->setId($category->getId())->delete();
    }
}
```